# Problem in answering a question related to Riemann integration.

Tags: real-analysis

**The question is** :

Let $f : [0,1] \longrightarrow \mathbb R$ be a continuous function such that $f(x) \geq x^{3}$ for all $x \in [0,1]$ with $\int_{0}^{1} f(x) dx = \frac {1} {4}$.Then $f(x) = x^{3}$ for all $x \in \mathbb [0,1]$.

I think the above relation holds good.But I cannot properly figure out why? Please help me.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint:** Recall If $g$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, $g(x)≥0$ on $[a,b]$ and $$\int_{a}^{b} g(x) =0$$ Then $g \equiv 0$

What is the "obvious" choice for $g$ to solve your problem using hint?

Comment: So, @ArpitKansal taking $g(x) = f(x) - x^{3}$ will do the trick.Isn't it?

Comment: @A.Chattopadhyay: You're right!